# How to enable cookies in Chromedriver with Webdriver?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use Selenium's Chromedriver to log in to a website which has cookies enabled. I got a message from the server that the browser has cookies disabled. How can I enable cookies in Chromedriver?

[image]

Comment: It should be enabled by default. Use your Selenium opened browser to http://www.whatismybrowser.com/, see what the result is.

Comment: Strangely whatismybrowser.com says that the cookies are enabled, but I get the message on the browser that the cookies are disabled(update the question with snapshot) I am trying to access https://ewf.companieshouse.gov.uk//seclogin?tc=1

Comment: @tintin any updates on this?

Answer (score 4):

ChromeDriver has cookie be enabled by default.

Please try the following steps:

1. Use FirefoxDriver/IEDriver, see what the site says.
2. Manually open a Chrome browser, see what the site says.
3. Try open [whatismybrowser.com](http://whatismybrowser.com) with ChromeDriver opened browser, see what it tells you.

If your site says cookie not enabled for FirefoxDriver/IEDriver/Manually opened Chrome, and [whatismybrowser.com](http://whatismybrowser.com) says your ChromeDriver opened browser has cookie enabled, then clearly something is wrong with your site, please try debug your site.

Comment: @tintin: Do you have any feedback on this? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

What I did to use an instance of Chrome with Selenium where I was logged in was to run the following Python code, which opens a new instance of Chrome.
If you already had Chrome open on your computer this will be a different instance of Chrome and you may see the Chrome app open in two different instances. With this new instance open I logged in to my account manually, then quit the new Chrome instance and ran the code again and then I was logged in.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "urlToWebsiteToLogin"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default") #path for MacOS
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True) #prevent window from closing
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
```

Remember to quit the Chrome instance before running the code again or you will get the following error:

> invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir