# Selenium and HTTP Cookies

Tags: c#, selenium, cookies, selenium-webdriver

I am currently having issues in regards to Selenium and its acceptance of HTTP cookies. When Selenium enters credentials into a login screen for a specific site it needs to login to, the login authentication fails as the login screen claims that HTTP cookies are disabled. I currently have selenium using a Firefox profile that is set to have cookies enabled and is loading the proper plugins etc.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = (new FirefoxProfileManager()).GetProfile("SeleniumProfile");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

In attempts to diagnose the issue, I directed selenium to https://www.whatismybrowser.com/ where it says that cookies are enabled. Additionally, when I login using the same Firefox session that selenium created and login myself there is no error and the login works. I searched high and low for similar issues however I couldn’t find a solution. Any help is greatly appreciated, and excuse my ignorance if there is a trivial solution.

UPDATE: I found a similar issue [How to enable cookies in Chromedriver with Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211006/how-to-enable-cookies-in-chromedriver-with-webdriver)  however, the solution is inconclusive.

Comment: are you modifying the user agent string at all?  i've seen weird apps that have an arbitrary user agent check, and "claim" that these things aren't enabled, even though they are.

Comment: No, I am not modifying the user agent string at all.