# Log in to facebook using selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I try to log in to facebook using selenium library but I occur some problems. After it inputs the credentials and click the login button I get an error which says:

```
Cookies Required
Cookies are not enabled on your browser. Please enable cookies in your browser preferences to continue.
```

I've looked over the internet for an answer so I've tried with `driver.manage().getCookies();` and I get the same result.

Here's my code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", DRIVERLOCATION);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().getCookies();


driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");

driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(USERNAME);
driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys(PASSWORD);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'u_0_')][@value='Log In']")).click();
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you get this message in the html body?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211006/how-to-enable-cookies-in-chromedriver-with-webdriver ...

Comment: After the login request is made It redirects me to another page which says that

Comment: @GhostCat I've tried with firefox and I get the same results and https://www.whatismybrowser.com/ says that the cookies are enabled

Comment: Funny. Maybe you should sue facebook. Maybe maybe they have something in place to avoid such "automation" log into their site.

Comment: haha, actually that may be a thing

Comment: still I could get it done in python so maybe I am missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know in the question I said that I try to reach www.facebook.com but in the real project I was reaching a profile.

It works just fine when you go to https://www.facebook.com but the `error occurs when your going to a profile or if you have second authentication activated.`