# Selenium: Login works sometimes. Enable cookies

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium to login to a website:

https://www.supersaas.es/schedule/Esportiu_Rocafort/Reserva_Piscina?view=free

The code is running in a Lambda function in AWS. The problem is that **sometimes** the website returns this message:

"Please clear your cookies - To login you need to enable cookies in your browser"

Here is a similar stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211006/how-to-enable-cookies-in-chromedriver-with-webdriver)

When I execute the code in my computer(macOS) the problem never happens. This is not the case in the Lambda function.

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1280x1696')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=0')
chrome_options.add_argument('--v=99')
chrome_options.add_argument('--single-process')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent='+UserAgent(verify_ssl=False).random)

chrome_options.binary_location = os.getcwd() + "/headless-chromium"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd() + "/chromedriver",chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.supersaas.es/schedule/Esportiu_Rocafort/Reserva_Piscina?view=free")

username = driver.find_element_by_id("name")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")

username.send_keys("ABC@gmail.com")
password.send_keys("ABC")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/form/fieldset/div[6]/button").click()

server_return_message = driver.find_element_by_id("flash").text
print(server_return_message)
```

Comment: Can you try adding incognito mode `chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')` ? This way it will not store cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from the **random user agent** you're using, try to print for each run the user agent that was used and see if the problem relates to a specific agent.

Hope this helps :D